# using \b with grep pattern

Tags: regex, bash

I am learning bash and I have come across regular expressions.
There is an exercise where I have to match a word and I tried to use `\b<word>\b` but for some reason it was not matched until I used `\\b<word>\\b`. I actually tried it out of desperation when I couldn't understand why `\b` wasn't working.

Comment: You should add the input you used

Comment: yes i guess i should have.Thanks. It was actually my etc/hosts file which had nothing but the loopback interface entries( 127.0.0.1 and ::1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are proabably using `grep \bword\b` which is really `grep bwordb` after bash parses the backslashes.

Use `grep '\bword\b'` (note the single-quotes).

Comment: yeah you are right i ended up figuring that out.stupid me.but i have a different question now.so i am trying to match the word "localhost" in a file that has "localhost" and "localhost.localdomain" but  they both get matched and  i know \b matches the empty string at the edge of a word, "." is not a word if i am correct, how can i get around this ?

Comment: grep "localhost" file | grep -v "localhost\." *should* get it.

Comment: No problem. Don't hold me to my former comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `grep -w word` to match whole words only.